# React Router renders two components instead of one

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to render two different components with the path `/acts` and `/acts/lite`. The problem is that when I go to `/acts/lite` I get both components rendered instead of just the one that correspond to this path...

For example, when I'm navigating to `/acts` I get this:
[image]

And when I'm navigating to `/acts/lite` the text `Test Acts` is still there...
[image]

This is my `Router`:

```
  <Router>
    <div>
      <App>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
        <div className="flexible-width container">
          <Route path="/acts" component={requireAuth(ActsPage)} />
          <Route path="/acts/lite/" component={requireAuth(ActsLitePage)} />
        </div>
      </App>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

`ActsPage` Component:

```
class ActsPage extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Test Acts
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ActsPage;
```

`ActsLitePage` Component:

```
class ActsLitePage extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Testing Acts Lite
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ActsLitePage;
```

And this is the Component that shows the sidebar with those two links:

```
var Sidebar = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var sidebarClass = this.props.isOpen ? 'sidebar open' : 'sidebar';
    return (
      <div className={sidebarClass}>
        <div><Link to="/acts/">Acts</Link></div>
        <div><Link to="/acts/lite/">Acts Lite</Link></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default Sidebar;
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong or why it behaves like this..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed "exact" in your route:

```
<Link exact to="/acts/">Acts</Link>
```